# StopWatch to Show Counter of Elapsed Time?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a textbox on my windows form that I am wanting to show the elapsed time that my procedure has taken, but I am not seeing any time counting in the textbox.  Below is my code

```
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
  private Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch()l

  private void btn_RashadSL()
  {
    watch.Start();
    //lots of code here that typically takes around 15 - 20 minutes to complete
  }
  private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    textbox1.Text = watch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Also one thing to note is to be careful to avoid Cross-Thread operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you have posted I'd say the problem is that at no point have you set up a timer to actually call the `timer_Tick` method.

Comment: At what portion would it be best for me to call the 'timer_Tick' method so that it updates every second?

Comment: When your form initialises, have a `Timer` member and have it call that function. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  (there are differences between this Timer and Threading.Timer, but not really applicable to your question).